# POSTGRES min/least value

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.3, distinct-on

I have a postgres 9.3 table with two columns. The first column has times and the second has routes. A route may have multiple times. I want to list all routes with their most minimum times. My table:

```
Times      Routes
07:15:00    Route a
09:15:00    Route a
08:15:00    Route b
11:30:00    Route b
09:15:00    Route c
12:00:00    Route c
```

What i want output:

```
 Times        Routes
 07:15:00     Route a
 08:15:00     Route b
 09:15:00     Route c
```

Any help would be appriciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: I know a 'least' function exists but each row in times column is always going  to be the least across that row. What i am looking for is a combination of a distinct select on routes column and least(time)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the [`MIN` aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-aggregate.html), and then grouping by the `Routes` column:

```
SELECT Routes, MIN(Times) FROM Table GROUP BY Routes
```

The `GROUP BY` clause is used to group rows together into a single row which have the same value for the field(s) specified in the `GROUP BY` clause. You can then use aggregate functions such as `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, `AVG`, ... to compute values from the rows which have been grouped together.

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct on(routes) routes
      ,times 
from p 
order by routes,times asc
```

---

[`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Will return the "*first*" row of each set of rows where the expression is equal.

As per doc.

> DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each
>   set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. [...] Note
>   that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is
>   used to ensure that the desired row appears first. [...] The DISTINCT
>   ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s).

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` clause is useful when it is used in conjunction with an aggregate function. For your question, to find minimum value of times across all input values for routes you can use the `GROUP BY` clause to break into groups and for each group, you will be calculating the time using `MIN` aggregate function.

You can achieve this using group by 
`select routes, min(times) from your_table group by routes`